# How do I manage iPhone on elementary os

Tags: settings, applications, files

I have an iPhone 6s and would like it to work like how it does when I plug it into windows (file manager detects it and I can see photos) is there a way of doing this or a program like iTunes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't find a solution on the Linux side, consider an IOS app called Phone Drive.

The app will start web and FTP servers on the phone providing direct upload/download access to your Camera Roll. Your other apps can easily "Share" their data with its temp directory, making nearly everything on the phone accessible to any device with a web browser or FTP client.  For all of $1.99.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phone-drive-file-storage-sync/id431033044

fcont